# HTTPS WebAPI self-host with authentication error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, https, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl-certificate

I have following error "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" when i implement project WebAPI mvc4 With Selt-host configuration.

-error detail: http://tinyurl.com/8tj8nek

-all code base on this article: http://tinyurl.com/3mdypd9

-I has do flowing steps to implement https protocol: (all have administrator permission)

STEP01:--------------Register Port For Service.-----------
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9900/ user=EVERYONE

STEP02:--------------Create The Root Certificate----------
makecert -sk RootCA -sky signature -pe -n CN=MySVR     -r -sr LocalMachine -ss Root MyWebAPI.cer

STEP03:-------------create the server certificate---------
makecert -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=MySVR     -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyWebAPI.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyWebAPI_SVR.cer

STEP04:------------register the server certificate--------

http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9900 certhash=99A8C41444622D6DC2FFB31F867601A75AAA444F appid={76cd6e8c-304a-4614-8aa7-939894c499dd} clientcertnegotiation=enable

what's wrong with me ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually add the self-signed certificate to your browser's list of trusted sites otherwise it will be rejected. An alternate possibility for certain testing situations with the Firefox browser is to install the add-on :
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/

Here's instructions for adding your cert to the trusted list in Firefox:
http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/FireFox.aspx